# Name threads in PyDev debug view

Tags: python, multithreading, debugging, pydev

PyDev's debug view shows the threads, however their names are cryptic:

[image: Cryptic thread names]

Is there a way to name these threads from within the python code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the names being displayed in PyDev are the ones assigned by default.

To fix that you can give a name to the thread when it's created:

```
threading.Thread(name=<name>, target=...)
```

or, later, just by setting the name attribute:

```
thread = threading.Thread(*args, **kwargs)
thread.name = <name>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using the [getName/setName API](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.getName) or setting *name* attribute on a thread.  Or you can set name when the [thread is created](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread).